# Switch column indices of a second matrix until highest match with the first matrix (binary values)

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

Starting point: two one-hot encoded arrays

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr1 = np.array([[1, 1, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1]])

arr2 = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1]])
```

Match arr1 and arr2: 4/9

**Aim: switch the columns in arr2 in such a way that the most digits match, and then give out the indices.**

---

switch column 0 and 1:

```
arr2b = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 1, 1]])
```

Match arr1 and arr2b: 6/9

---

Output when using the chosen column indices on arr2, for example with the help of a dataframe:

```
col_idx = [1, 0, 2] # (column 0 and 1 are switched here)
pd.DataFrame(data=arr2).iloc[:,col_idx]
```

[image: output]

But this might be not the best outcome. How to find the best column indices for arr2 by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
arr1 = np.array([[1, 1, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1]])

arr2 = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1]])
```

All permutations of switched column indices can be shown as follows:

```
prm = list(permutations(range(arr2.shape[1])))
```

is: [(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]

We loop through all of these permutations and check how many numbers are hit:

```
matches = [(arr1==np.array(b[:,x])).sum() for x in prm]
```

is: [4, 4, 6, 8, 2, 4]

```
prm_idx = np.argmax(matches)
```

is: 3

```
best_col_idx = list(prm[prm_idx])
```

is: [1, 2, 0]

```
arr2[:,best_col_idx]
```

is:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
```

Or in a df:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=arr2).iloc[:,best_col_idx]
```

[image]

Check:

```
(arr1==np.array(arr2[:,[1, 2, 0]]))
```

is:

```
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Thus, 8 x `True` is right, the maximizing column index switch was right.